# My execute_script command in selenium webdriver for python is causing an error on the following line

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm brand new to selenium webdriver for python, and I've run into a problem I can't solve.  I've searched for an answer, but didn't see anything.  I apologize if I've missed it.

We had the following command in a selenium IDE script:

```
getEval | window.$("#DestList option").attr('selected','selected')
```

In my webdriver python script, I made that command look like this:

```
driver.execute_script("return window.$("#DestList option").attr('selected','selected')")
```

When I run the python script, whatever line follows the execute_script line gets an error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Which leads me to believe something is missing from my execute_script command.  Can someone tell me what might be missing or where I'm going wrong?

thanks in advance for your help and patience.

Ed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just about the quotes inside the script, fix it (tested, worked for me):

```
driver.execute_script("return window.$('#DestList option').attr('selected','selected')")
```